# Django - override existing data, after admin approval?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have been tasked with adding some new functionality to an existing view. Basically, on user signup if the company is already in the database, I am sending an email to an admin, saying "User wants to claim company". If admin approves, that user will be added to the company, and I want to override the previous info (address, phone, etc.) with the info this user put in at registration. I thought the best way to do this was to add a field to the `Account` model, called `is_approved` and set it to `False`, and when the admin approves, they will set it to `True` and the new info will be stored, overriding the existing data. I have a `Company` model, and a `Pending_Company`model, both with the same exact info.

My view...

```
        company_obj = Company.objects.filter(I am filtering the DB here)

        if not company_obj:
            """If no company match, create new one"""

            new_company = Company.objects.create(
                name=company.title(),
                zip=int(zip_code),
                primary_email=email,
                website=website,
                phone_no=phone_no,
                street=street,
                city=city,
                state=state,
            )
            new_company.owner.add(user)

        else:
            """Add employee to company, send email to admin for approval, 
            if approved, update company instance with new data."""


            # If DEBUG = True
            send_mail('Test Subject', 'Test message', 'test@gmail.com',
                      ['testemail@gmail.com', ], fail_silently=False)

            pending_company = PendingCompanyDetail.objects.create(
                name=company.title(),
                zip=int(zip_code),
                primary_email=email,
                website=website,
                phone_no=phone_no,
                street=street,
                city=city,
                state=state,
            )
            pending_company.owner.add(user)

            if user.is_approved:
                company_obj = pending_company
```

the `else` statement is where I am getting confused, It is not updating the `company_obj` instance with the new `pending_company` info.

I kind of understand why, because on account creation the `is_approved` is defaulted to `False`. I'm really trying to figure out a work around for this, when that boolean is flipped to True, how can I trigger that override?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct but you need to understand that what you’re trying to accomplish is asynchronous. You need to await the approval( aka waiting for a response from admin) and then make that object a real company object in your data base. Since this waiting for the approval can take sometime, I like your approach of creating a temporary table for pending companies. You need to send the id of the pending object as a query parameter in a link within the email, and that is the end of this view. Finally, you should create another view on that link’s endpoint (the one that admins click to see the information and decide whether it’s approved or not). The purpose of the second view is to create a company object based on a specific pending object info. You wouldn’t really need the is_approved field.

Comment: In the case that I am "admin", and I just see an email get sent to me, and I go into the admin to review, and then turn that user's `is_approved` to True, I still don't really know how to trigger that update. I'm thinking I need some sort of custom function. Right now turning `is_approved` to True, I'm getting nothing :/

Comment: Of course, nothing happens. Because every time your view gets called, `is_approved` is set to False. If you want to stick with your approach, you might use [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)